# Checking File Size of an Uploaded Image

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Currently, I am passing an uploaded file through html to a php script. How can I check the file size of the uploaded image?

Here is my html:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post"   name="changer" class="login" style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px;">
  <h3>Avatar: </h3>
  <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
  <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
  <input value="Update Avatar" type="submit">
  </form>
```

Here is my php:

```
  // Temporary file name stored on the server
  $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

  // Read the file
  $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
  fclose($fp);
```

Note: I have already checked to make sure the file exists. I am just trying to make sure the file size meets the requirements for my server.

Comment: You already have the file size in there with `filesize($tmpName)` in bytes. :P So simply do something like `$size = filesize($tmpName)` or you can use the built in size fetched by PHP upon upload via `$_FILES['image']['size']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_FILES["image"]["size"]
```

That will give you the size in bytes, which you can confirm before moving the temporary file to your server.

Comment: @user3496349 Yep, that would confirm that the image size is below a certain threshold, set as `$minimumbites`. Just remember that this is in bytes, so most people convert it to kilobytes by dividing it by 1024

Comment: You mean multiplying it by 1024.

Comment: @user3496349 nope, dividing it. 1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes, so you would divide to get kilobytes.